# search icon not properly appending with search form on small screens in Bootstrap 4

Tags: search, bootstrap-4, dropdown

I have used dropdown for search form like when the search icon is clicked the search form appears. It works and is positioned as expected but when the breakpoint reaches the small screen size, the search form doesn't get properly append with the search icon. You can observe that by running the code and viewing on small screen.

```css
html,body {
font-family: "Roboto", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 1.42857143;
color: #333333;
background-color: #f0f0f0;
width: 100%;
}
#NavigationSection .bg-light{
    background: white !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Website</title>
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700,300,100" rel="stylesheet" >

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/stle.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>

<!-- Navigation -->
<section id="NavigationSection">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
         <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">LOGO</a>
           <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navNavbar"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
           <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navNavbar">
             <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active"><a href="index.html" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a></li>
                 <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="search" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="padding-bottom: 0px;padding-top: 3px;"><i class="fas fa-search fa-2x"></i></a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="search" style="min-width:17rem;padding: 0.5rem;float:left">
                            <form class="form-inline my-lg-0" method="get" action="results.php">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" name="user_query" required>
                                    <div class="input-group-append"><button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" value="Search" name="search"><i class="fas fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    </button></div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </li>  
                </ul>
           </div>
  </div>
    </nav>
</section>


<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following line,

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" value="Search" name="search">
```

Remove `my-2`, see below (which is responsible for margins in the y axis).

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-success my-sm-0" type="submit" value="Search" name="search">
```

I am sure this will do the trick. I hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: @Shery I am glad to hear :)